# Capturing stream that has multiple frames

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to capture a stream that has multiple "frames" (not sure that's what you would call it but it has multiple 5 second streams inside of it) with FFmpeg and saving to file. When I put it into Quicktime player and play it works fine, however when I put it into FFmpeg and review the final file it seems that the audio and video are out of sync and the video frequently stops. I think this may be because it is stopping to switch to the new 5 second video but i'm not sure. This is the command I am using:

```
ffmpeg \
    -v 9 \
    -loglevel 99 \
    -y \
    -re \
    -hwaccel auto \
    -threads 4 \
    -user-agent "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/528.18 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/7A341 Safari/528.16" \
    -i "url here" \
    -ac 2 \
    -strict -2 \
    -c:a aac \
    test.mov
```

In the FFmpeg log this frequently happens:

```
frame=  242 fps=102 q=29.0 size=     252kB time=00:00:06.33 bitrate= 325.9kbits/
frame=  279 fps= 96 q=29.0 size=     252kB time=00:00:07.57 bitrate= 272.8kbits/
frame=  301 fps= 87 q=29.0 size=     252kB time=00:00:08.30 bitrate= 248.7kbits/
frame=  319 fps= 79 q=29.0 size=     252kB time=00:00:08.90 bitrate= 231.9kbits/
frame=  338 fps= 74 q=29.0 size=     252kB time=00:00:09.54 bitrate= 216.5kbits/
frame=  354 fps= 70 q=29.0 size=     252kB time=00:00:10.07 bitrate= 205.0kbits/
skipping 5 segments ahead, expired from playlists
[https @ 0x7f9d81e10380] No trailing CRLF found in HTTP header.
frame=  355 fps= 51 q=29.0 size=     252kB time=00:00:10.11 bitrate= 204.3kbits/
[hls,applehttp @ 0x7f9d83001000] No longer receiving playlist 6
[hls,applehttp @ 0x7f9d83001000] No longer receiving playlist 7
[hls,applehttp @ 0x7f9d83001000] No longer receiving playlist 8
skipping 3 segments ahead, expired from playlists
[https @ 0x7f9d81f006a0] No trailing CRLF found in HTTP header.
```

Any ideas how I could smooth out the final file would be greatly appreciated.